Incorrect permission of copied files from Ubuntu to Windows using rsync on ssh
After copying files from Ubuntu to Windows using rsync on ssh, the copied files and folder have permissions that only creator have full access and other users including SYSTEM and Administrators have only special permissions.
Root folder permissions:

Sometimes other users can't open or copy the files.
When opening Properties ➝ Security for the files/folders received message "The permissions on <file/folder name> are incorrectly ordered, which may cause some entries to be ineffective"
Only after running the command icacls "<path to the folder where stored problematic files>" /reset /T /C , other users can use the files/folders correctly
Ubuntu machine: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.10.120-tegra aarch64)
Windows machine: Windows 11 pro. OS build: 22557.1
On windows installed rsync using cygwin
Rsync versions on Ubuntu: 3.1.3
Rsync version on Windows(cygwin): 3.3.0
Rsync command rsync -avz -e ssh /path/to/test_folder user@windows machine:/cygdrive/d/test_folder
Permissions of copied file link:

Permissions on Ubuntu:

Permissions on Windows after copying

Permissions on Windows after reset to default


What is the permissions of the root folder containing the files and folders you are transferring? Provide screenshots for clarity purposes.

Why are you using Cygwin instead of configuring OpenSSH which is built-into Windows as an optional windows feature? It seems your issues are connected to Cygwin.

@Ramhound Added screenshots. I'm using Cygwin for rsync. rsync should be installed on 2 machines to copy files over ssh.

You can try adding --chmod=ugo=rwX to give new files the destination-default permissions (while leaving existing files unchanged)

It doesn't work

@Cpt.Whale : What is the meaning of X? I guess it is not equivalent to x.

It would help if you would explain in an example the (Linux) permissions of some source file, and the Windows permissions of the copied file. Also explain in what respect this is different from what rsync does. Perhaps it also makes sense to explain what file system you are using on both platforms. Due to the differences in the security models, I would imagine that rsync is following a somewhat restrictive policy, to ensure that it does not give too general permissions on the destination.

@user1934428 Added screenshots of permissions on Ubuntu, permissions on Windows after copying and permissions after reset to default permissions.

@user1934428 capital X grants execute permissions only for directories, and for files a user already has execute permissions for

I'm not really a Windows guy, but according to the screenshot, the permissions for "everyone" is R and W, and this is the same in the original files. But I admit that I'm not the right person for this, because I don't know the Windows permission system. My approach would be that, for ease of debugging, I would create a single directory with a single file in it on linux, and rsync this directory to your Windows system. This should then be a reproducible case for everyone.
